# UITextView always returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I am trying to write custom text on a `UITextView IBOutlet` variable. However, due to some reason the compiler says the value is nil ? I checked the outlet connections. They look fine to me. I am missing out something else. Could anyone help me with this ?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CellClickController: UIViewController{   
    @IBOutlet var name: UITextView!

    //var urgentCenter: UrgentCenterDetails = UrgentCenterDetails()

    func viewDidLoad(index: Int) {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //println("index: \(index)")
        if name == nil{
            println("I am nil")
        }
        else{
            name.text = "Hello"
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: recommend you to update your Xcode version to the latest beta6

Comment: @Ezimet did it work on beta6  ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    if name == nil{
        println("I am nil")
    }
    else{
        name.text = "Hello"
    }
}
```

In your code the syntax of `viewDidLoad` method was wrong, so the `func` `viewDidLoad` is not worked.

Comment: Try removing the existing `IBOutlet` connection and add again, then check.